# Deleteing from memory after reference has returned

Tags: c++

I have a question about deleting things from memory in C++, and what will and will not exist any longer.  If I create a queue in C++ (standard library), add two elements to it, then call front(), store it in a regular variable (no pointer).  Then I call pop() on the queue.  The variable i stored will still exist right?  What happens if something edits the memory address where the pointer in queue used to live?  Does that mean the local variable i stored earlier is no longer valid since it was created from a reference?

Thanks for any clarifications.

Comment: Your question makes sense, but it would be much easier to express if you just wrote a sample code

Comment: Does "regular variable" mean a *reference variable*?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "pointer in queue" or "editing the memory address". If you reword your question with things that exist, the question goes away :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer in code:

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // "Q: If I create a queue in C++..."
    std::queue<int> q;

    // "...add two elements to it..."
    q.push(42);
    q.push(1729);

    // "...then call front(), store it in a regular variable (no pointer)..."
    int i = q.front();

    // "...Then I call pop() on the queue..."
    q.pop();

    // ...The variable i stored will still exist right?"

    // A: "Yes, of course! And it retained its value:"
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Moreover:

> "What happens if something edits the memory address where the pointer in queue used to live?"

We did not store a pointer in the queue (see above)! Anyway, if you meant "*What happens if the region of memory where the queue had its popped element stored gets released or overwritten*", the answer is that we stored a **copy** of that object in `i`, and `i` lives in a completely different region of memory.

> "Does that mean the local variable `i` stored earlier is no longer valid since it was created from a reference?"

No, it is still valid, because even though it was assigned from an object which was referenced through the return value of `front()`, we made a **copy** of that object!

Comment: So what would happen if the queue was of type `int*`?

Comment: @MasterGberry: And if the variable `i` were of type `int*` as well? And you stored pointers in the queue?

Comment: Errrr, I actually think I just came to the understanding.  So when you return a reference of some object you are copying it into the variable right?

Comment: @MasterGberry: Correct, you are copying it. If your variable `i` were of type `int&`, on the other hand, that would initialize a reference from the returned reference (so you would end up with a reference to the object stored *in the queue!*). In this case, popping the element from the queue and then trying to access it through `i` would give undefined behavior, because the object `i` is bound to has been destroyed when popping. However, if `i` is of type `int` (as in the example above), then all you do is creating a separate object, which lives at a different memory address (in short, a copy)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you aren't storing pointers in the queue, but instead actual values or objects, then when you store front() to a regular variable what you're really doing is a copy (if it's an object, the actual copy constructor will be called). The copy won't be effected when you pop() the element of the queue.

Comment: Not true front() returns by reference not value

Comment: @Mppl When you "store front() to a regular variable" a copy does occur, even though front() returns by reference.

Comment: @JoeGauterin Unless it's also a reference.  :)

Comment: @Drew: Then it's not a regular variable (I made some assumptions about what 'regular variable' means here) :)

Comment: Sorry,you're right. Assigning to a variable really creates a copy.

Comment: What would happen if the queue was of type `int *`?

Answer (score -2):

If you store it with front() and you pop it afterwards your object does no longer exist (supposing you're using queue from STL)

This happens because front() returns the contained object by reference not copy.